# Yasnippet doesn't work when tab-always-indent set to true

Tags: yasnippet

It annoys, when autocompletion & indentation both gets called on `TAB` press. So, i configured to use `TAB` key only for indentation as,

```
(setq tab-always-indent t)
```

Now, when i enable `yas-minor-mode` to place code snippets, it doesn't work since i have bound `TAB` key only for indentation. Is there any other key binding (or) `yasnippet` function that can i use/call to get this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [yas-snippet manual](https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-expansion.html#org87a6f68):

## Trigger key

yas-expand tries to expand a snippet abbrev (also known as snippet key) before point.

When yas-minor-mode is enabled, it binds yas-expand to TAB and  by default, however, you can freely set it to some other key:

```el
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "<tab>") nil)
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "TAB") nil)
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "<the new key>") 'yas-expand)
```